# Linux - Where to place manuals and docs for user binaries?

Tags: linux, software-installation, man, documentation

For applications installed via system package manager, binaries, man pages, and docs go in `/usr/bin/`, `/usr/share/man/man<n>/`, and `/usr/share/doc/<app-name>/` respectively. For example:

[image: example application]

According to [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#:%7E:text=user-specific%20executable%20files%20may%20be%20stored%20in%20%24home%2F.local%2Fbin.), for applications installed for a single user, the binaries go in `$HOME/.local/bin`. But I cannot find mentions of man pages and docs. (I imagine it would be inappropriate for them to go in `/usr` when the corresponding binaries aren't installed system-wide.) So where should they go, and is there a standard/specification for this?

Comment: Read `man hier`, it's the Linux Filesystem Hieracy document, which explains where things go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications installed for a single user are normally installed as that user and may not have permission to modify existing directories under `/usr`.

Since the user is likely the one that installed the software, the documentation can go wherever permissions allow as they are the only user that needs access to it.  I am not aware of any universal standard for the preferred location of user installed documentation.

If you are looking to organize everything in relation to `$HOME/.local/bin`, you should be able to just replace the prefix of those installed directories and files to use `$HOME/.local` instead of `/usr`.  Then the files in your examples would be located in directories such as `$HOME/.local/share` and `$HOME/.local/bin`.